# Python: how to iterate over dataframes while using their name as a string?

Tags: python, pandas

I have three different `Pandas` dataframes

```
df_1
df_2
df_3
```

I would like to loop over the dataframes, do some computations, and store the output using the `name` of the dataframe. In other words, something like this

```
for my_df in [df_1, df_2, df_3]:
  my_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
  my_df.to_csv('mypath/' + my_df +'.csv')
```

Output files expected:

`'mypath/df_1.csv'`,  `'mypath/df_2.csv'` and  `'mypath/df_3.csv'`

I am struggling doing so because `df_1` is an object, and not a string.
Any ideas how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another more general solution is create `dict` with column names and then loop by `items()`:

```
d = {'df_1':df_1,'df_2':df_3, 'df_3':df_3}
for k, my_df in d.items():
    my_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    my_df.to_csv('mypath/' + k +'.csv')
```

Another possible solution is use another `list` with dataframes names, then `enumerate` and get value of `name` by position:

```
names = ['a','b','c']
print ({names[i]: df for i, df in enumerate([df_1, df_2, df_3])})
```

Comment: thank jezrael but I dont want any manual mapping. What if I have 100 dataframes??

Comment: Use dict comprehension for mapping ;)

Comment: @jezrael dict comprehension you mean?

Comment: Yes, exactly, sorry.

Comment: ok so there is no way from say a dataframe called `jezrael_the_pythonista` to get the string `jezrael_the_pythonista` without doing the mapping myself? like some `df.get_name_as_str()` method?

Comment: I am not python expert, but I think if yes, so not easy.

Comment: @Noobie The object pointed by `jezrael_the_pythonista`  may have a lot of other names so it is not actually possible to do that.

Comment: yeah the object points to something but... we can see the name of the pointer right? :D

Comment: @Noobie You can iterate over all names and check with `is` but that's bad practice in my opinion. Dictionaries are much better.

Answer (score 1):

To store df as csv using to_csv method we need a string path.

So we enumerate over the list. This gives us 2 variable in the for loop.
1st variable is the index of the loop iteration. It's like a counter.

So basically `enumerate` gives us a counter object on the loop.

We are using the counter value to create a string of the index. 
Which we use to create a unique file name to store.

```
for idx, my_df in enumerate([df_1, df_2, df_3]):
  my_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
  my_df.to_csv('mypath/df_' + str(idx + 1) +'.csv')
```

Comment: This names them `df_0`, `df_1`, `df_2`  and makes assumptions that the names of the dataframes always fits that pattern.  To get this pattern correct at least update the answer with `enumerate(enumerate([df_1, df_2, df_3], 1)`